# webpack babel jsnext:main and dependencies transpiling

Tags: webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

I opened the following issues last week but nobody seem to know the answer:

- [github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/488](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/488)
- [github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2902](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2902)

I really do not understand what's the current status in `webpack` / `babel-loader` in transpiling dependencies in `node_modules`, can anyone please clarify? I tried to stick to every issue opened everywhere.

1. Is `webpack` / `babel-loader` transpiling `jsnext:main` file?
2. If yes, is `webpack` / `babel-loader` transpiling `jsnext:main` file in `node_modules` even if `node_modules` is in exclude key?

My situation:

```
rules: [{
    test: /\.(js|mjs)$/i,
    exclude: [/node_modules/],
    use: [{
        loader: 'babel-loader', //settings specified in package.json
    },{
        loader: 'eslint-loader', //settings specified in package.json
    }
}]
```

In my dependency `package.json` I tried:

```
"main": "index.js", <= not working (not transpiled)
"jsnext:main": "index.js", <= not working (not transpiled)
"module": "index.js", <= not working (not transpiled)
```

Neither is working without removing `exclude: [/node_modules/],` but this can't be used in any medium-to-big sized project because of infinite compilation times.

But then: why is https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/es/package.json any different from my https://github.com/damianobarbati/react-create-app/blob/master/package.json? 
`lodash-es` is getting transpiled even being in node_modules (and excluded) but my `react-create-app` is not: HELP!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `babel-loader` is not transpiling anything in `node_modules` when you exclude `node_modules` from the rule. The fields like `jsnext:main` or `module` have nothing to do with loaders/rules. When a package is imported, webpack decides what file it should use based on [`resolve.mainFields`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-mainfields) and then it will check which rules it should apply to that file. Usually these files are already transpiled, except that they contain ES modules (see [Rollup - `pkg.module`](https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/pkg.module)).

If you want to transpile any module that has a `module` or `jsnext:main` field, you could use the rule from Jason Miller [developit/transpile-esnext-modules.js](https://gist.github.com/developit/081148d83348ebe9a1bc1ba0707e1bb8) which determines whether the module should be included or not (`include` and `exclude` also accept a function).

Comment: then why is lodash-es being transpiled? Just ES6 files in there. Even without that rules webpack is transpiling it :|

Comment: They are already transpiled. What's in the GitHub repository is not what is being published to npm. See the published source [unpkg - lodash](https://unpkg.com/lodash@4.17.4/lodash.js) (or look at `./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js`). Most libraries write their source with modern features and build the necessary files before publishing. A good example is Redux, which has a simple [build process](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/c1953b04cf48b2973aa8e2197d5b46ec36adbd59/package.json#L22-L26). The output directories (`es`, `lib`, `dist`), that are published, are even in its `.gitignore`.